# How to output data on one line per ID in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

This works to get me all the data I need, but outputs a separate row for each side of the UNION when what I really want is to get all parent contacts on the same row as the student ID. That is, I want a row with **a.id** and then all the info for **contact_1, contact_2, contact_3 and contact_4** in the same row. I'm guessing UNION was the wrong choice...

```
SELECT final.* 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
        --Name 1 in P1 household
        a.id
        ,a.name1_web_user_id as contact_1_id
        ,a.name1_full_name as contact_1_name
        ,case 'Name1:Mobile' 
            when Other_No_Type_1 then Other_No_1
            when Other_No_Type_2 then Other_No_2
            when Other_No_Type_3 then Other_No_3
            when Other_No_Type_4 then Other_No_4
            end as contact_1_mobile
        ,a.email as contact_1_email
       
        --Name 2 in P1 household
        ,a.name2_web_user_id as contact_2_id
        ,a.name2_full_name as contact_2_name
        ,case 'Name2:Mobile' 
            when Other_No_Type_1 then Other_No_1
            when Other_No_Type_2 then Other_No_2
            when Other_No_Type_3 then Other_No_3
            when Other_No_Type_4 then Other_No_4
            end as contact_2_mobile
        ,a.EMAIL_2 as contact_2_email
            
    FROM rg_student s left outer join rg_addr a on s.id = a.id
                WHERE  (
                (a.addr_code='P1' AND a.rg_active = 'Y') AND ((a.name1_web_user_id is not null) OR (a.name2_web_user_id is not null))
                            AND a.id in(SELECT id from rg_student where student_group='Student')
                        )
    UNION
    
        SELECT 
        --Name 1 in P2 household
        a.id
        ,a.name1_web_user_id as contact_3_id
        ,a.name1_full_name as contact_3_name
        ,case 'Name1:Mobile' 
            when Other_No_Type_1 then Other_No_1
            when Other_No_Type_2 then Other_No_2
            when Other_No_Type_3 then Other_No_3
            when Other_No_Type_4 then Other_No_4
            end as contact_3_mobile
        ,a.email as contact_3_email
        
        --Name 2 in P2 household
        ,a.name2_web_user_id as contact_4_id
        ,a.name2_full_name as contact_4_name
        ,case 'Name2:Mobile' 
            when Other_No_Type_1 then Other_No_1
            when Other_No_Type_2 then Other_No_2
            when Other_No_Type_3 then Other_No_3
            when Other_No_Type_4 then Other_No_4
            end as contact_4_mobile
        ,a.EMAIL_2 as contact_4_email
            
    FROM rg_student s left outer join rg_addr a on s.id = a.id
                WHERE  (
                        (a.addr_code='P2' AND a.rg_active = 'Y') AND ((a.name1_web_user_id is not null) OR (a.name2_web_user_id is not null))
                            AND a.id in(SELECT id from rg_student where student_group='Student')
                        )                
        )final
    ORDER BY final.id
```

I've tried to replace the UNION with JOIN, as guided, and simplified the select as follows, but now get error about FROM being in the wrong place.

```
        SELECT 
        --Name 1 in P1 household
        s.id
        ,a.name1_web_user_id as contact_1_id
        ,a.name1_full_name as contact_1_name
        ,case 'Name1:Mobile' 
            when a.Other_No_Type_1 then Other_No_1
            when a.Other_No_Type_2 then Other_No_2
            when a.Other_No_Type_3 then Other_No_3
            when a.Other_No_Type_4 then Other_No_4
            end as contact_1_mobile
        ,a.email as contact_1_email
       
        --Name 2 in P1 household
        ,a.name2_web_user_id as contact_2_id
        ,a.name2_full_name as contact_2_name
        ,case 'Name2:Mobile' 
            when a.Other_No_Type_1 then Other_No_1
            when a.Other_No_Type_2 then Other_No_2
            when a.Other_No_Type_3 then Other_No_3
            when a.Other_No_Type_4 then Other_No_4
            end as contact_2_mobile
        ,a.email_2 as contact_2_email
            
        --Name 1 in P2 household
        s.id
        ,b.name1_web_user_id as contact_3_id
        ,b.name1_full_name as contact_3_name
        ,case 'Name1:Mobile' 
            when b.Other_No_Type_1 then Other_No_1
            when b.Other_No_Type_2 then Other_No_2
            when b.Other_No_Type_3 then Other_No_3
            when b.Other_No_Type_4 then Other_No_4
            end as contact_3_mobile
        ,b.email as contact_3_email
        
        --Name 2 in P2 household
        ,b.name2_web_user_id as contact_4_id
        ,b.name2_full_name as contact_4_name
        ,case 'Name2:Mobile' 
            when b.Other_No_Type_1 then Other_No_1
            when b.Other_No_Type_2 then Other_No_2
            when b.Other_No_Type_3 then Other_No_3
            when b.Other_No_Type_4 then Other_No_4
            end as contact_4_mobile
        ,b.email_2 as contact_4_email
            
    FROM rg_student s
        left outer join rg_addr a on s.id=a.id
        WHERE  ((a.addr_code='P1' AND a.rg_active = 'Y') 
                AND s.id in(SELECT id from rg_student where student_group='Student'))
        left outer join rg_addr b on s.id=b.id
        WHERE  ((a.addr_code='P2' AND b.rg_active = 'Y') 
                 AND s.id in(SELECT id from rg_student where student_group='Student'))
```

This now gives me the single row per student that I need, but also disregards my need to (SELECT id from rg_student where student_group='Student') in the FROM, so it's now returning all students in any group (incl. withdrawn, graduate, etc.). I hear that I can't use WHERE in the FROM, but not sure how to define the student_group I need.

```
       SELECT DISTINCT
       --Name 1 in P1 household
       s.id
       ,a.name1_web_user_id as contact_1_id
       ,a.name1_full_name as contact_1_name
       ,case 'Name1:Mobile' 
           when a.Other_No_Type_1 then a.Other_No_1
           when a.Other_No_Type_2 then a.Other_No_2
           when a.Other_No_Type_3 then a.Other_No_3
           when a.Other_No_Type_4 then a.Other_No_4
           end as contact_1_mobile
       ,a.email as contact_1_email
      
       --Name 2 in P1 household
       ,a.name2_web_user_id as contact_2_id
       ,a.name2_full_name as contact_2_name
       ,case 'Name2:Mobile' 
           when a.Other_No_Type_1 then a.Other_No_1
           when a.Other_No_Type_2 then a.Other_No_2
           when a.Other_No_Type_3 then a.Other_No_3
           when a.Other_No_Type_4 then a.Other_No_4
           end as contact_2_mobile
       ,a.email_2 as contact_2_email
           
       --Name 1 in P2 household
       ,s.id
       ,b.name1_web_user_id as contact_3_id
       ,b.name1_full_name as contact_3_name
       ,case 'Name1:Mobile' 
           when b.Other_No_Type_1 then b.Other_No_1
           when b.Other_No_Type_2 then b.Other_No_2
           when b.Other_No_Type_3 then b.Other_No_3
           when b.Other_No_Type_4 then b.Other_No_4
           end as contact_3_mobile
       ,b.email as contact_3_email
       
       --Name 2 in P2 household
       ,b.name2_web_user_id as contact_4_id
       ,b.name2_full_name as contact_4_name
       ,case 'Name2:Mobile' 
           when b.Other_No_Type_1 then b.Other_No_1
           when b.Other_No_Type_2 then b.Other_No_2
           when b.Other_No_Type_3 then b.Other_No_3
           when b.Other_No_Type_4 then b.Other_No_4
           end as contact_4_mobile
       ,b.email_2 as contact_4_email
           
   FROM rg_student s
       left outer join rg_addr a on s.id=a.id
       AND  a.addr_code='P1' AND a.rg_active = 'Y' 
       AND s.id in(SELECT id from rg_student where student_group='Student')
           left outer join rg_addr b on s.id=b.id
           AND  a.addr_code='P2' AND b.rg_active = 'Y' 
           AND s.id in(SELECT id from rg_student where student_group='Student')
```

Comment: Please post some sample data and expected output

Comment: Use `Join` not `Union`

Comment: Thank you Plirkee, but I'm afraid I'm not having success with JOIN, probably because I don't know how to properly identify the two SELECTs as tables to be joined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `union` creates other rows for each student's `id`.

To put all the contact info on one row per `id`, you have to join your `rg_addr` to `rg_student` twice, with the difference in the condition for `addr_code`, like so:

```sql
select s.id,
  a.name1_web_user_id contact_1_id,
  a.name1_full_name contact_1_name,
  a.email contact_1_email,
  ... --other info of name 1 in P1 household
  a.name2_web_user_id contact_2_id,
  a.name2_full_name contact_2_name,
  a.email_2 contact_2_email,
  ... --other info of name 2 in P1 household
  b.name1_web_user_id contact_3_id,
  b.name1_full_name contact_3_name,
  b.email contact_3_email,
  ... --other info of name 1 in P2 household
  b.email_2 contact_4_email,
  b.name2_web_user_id contact_4_id,
  b.email_2 contact_4_email,
  ... --other info of name 2 in P2 household
from rg_student s
  left outer join rg_addr a on s.id=a.id
    and a.addr_code='P1' and a.rg_active='Y'
    and ... --and other required conditions
  left outer join rg_addr b on s.id=b.id
    and a.addr_code='P2' and b.rg_active='Y'
    and ... --and other required conditions
```

Note that what I put for `id` is `s` prefix instead of `a` to make sure there's a student ID in case the student does not have corresponding `rg_addr` record.

---

Edit:
Additional code changes for student group requirement:

```
...
FROM rg_student s
  left outer join rg_addr a on s.id=a.id
    AND  a.addr_code='P1' AND a.rg_active = 'Y' 
    --AND s.id in(SELECT id from rg_student where student_group='Student')
  left outer join rg_addr b on s.id=b.id
    AND  a.addr_code='P2' AND b.rg_active = 'Y' 
    --AND s.id in(SELECT id from rg_student where student_group='Student')
WHERE s.student_group='Student'
```

Comment: Junjie, thank you for your comment. I tried to follow your direction, but keep getting errors. I simplified the select and I think I used your directions properly, but I'm maybe not seeing straight at this point. Do you see anything obviously wrong with it as I tried to correct it? I'm not sure where to put the new statement, so am pasting it back into my original question.

Comment: You're missing a comma after `contact_2_email`. And replace your `WHERE` keywords with `AND` because `WHERE` keyword is not allowed there.

Comment: Three a.m. is definitely not my best time. Thank you for your support. I made the correction, and a few others I found (columns ambiguously defined), and got the layout I needed. However, the output now includes students in all groups (i.e. Student, Graduate, etc) rather than only the student group='Student'. Do I need to get rid of the WHERE in the subquery (SELECT id from rg_student where student_group='Student')? Not sure how to do that. I pasted the new query above. Thank you.

Comment: ah.. ok.. at the very end of the query, you can use the `where` clause for that. `WHERE` s.student_group=`Student` to filter the main table `rg_student` and remove the `student_group` condition from the join clause. I appended that to my answer.